Nginx: only shows website when port is specified
I have the following configuration in /etc/nginx/conf.d/new_sites.conf:
server  {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name website.xyz www.website.xyz;

   location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
   }

}

server  {
  listen 80;
  server_name 123.456.78.901;
  return 301 http://website.xyz;
}

The /etc/nginx/sites-available/default contains this:
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

Directory /etc/nginx/sites-enabled is empty.
When I go directly to IP address it redirects to website.xyz and shows the domain registrar's page.
When I go to website.xyz I see the domain registrar's page.
My website is running on port 8081. When I go to IP:8081 it shows the website, just like when I go to website.xyz:8081.
I'm not sure why that is, since I tried to include the location for the listen 80 port as localhost:8081.

Please add output of nginx -T to the question so we can see the configuration used by nginx.

/etc/nginx/conf.d implies the directory layout used by RHEL and derivatives. /etc/nginx/sites-available implies the directory layout used by Debian and derivatives. To get a definitive picture of what is going on here you'd need to provide every config file used nginx. Or you could have told us what distribution of nginx you were using and why you've got a mixture of naming conventions.

When I go to website.xyz I see the domain registrar's page.

The DNS record for website.xyz is not pointing to your site.
You may have updated this already, however DNS is designed to be very cacheable. Check the config on your DNS hosting.

I use Ubuntu. DNS record is pointing to my IP. I can reach the website by going to website.xys:8081

I tried going to website.xyz again and it works - from PC. I see the main page of the website (same result with IP:8081 and IP. From mobile, however, website.xyz still the registrar's page. It's all very weird

Figured it out. A/CNAME records were off, I think
